# Windows Home Server 2011: My Computer and Disk Properties show old Label after rename

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-home-server, label

I have a Windows Home Server 2011 box (based on Windows Server 2008 R2).

For ease of use I label my data drives with what is on them:

`Data (E:) [500 GB SATA]` `Data Backup (R:) [500 GB USB]`

My Data drive (and so it's backup drive) recently became near full so I added an internal HDD and an external HDD, moved everything except my photos to the new drives, re-labeling `E` and `R` to `Photos` and `Photos Backup` respectively - no drive letters were changed, just new ones added.

Now in Disk Management I have the following layout:

`Photos (E:) [500 GB SATA]` `Data (F:) [2 TB SATA]` `Photos Backup (R:) [500 GB USB]` `Data Backup (T:) [2 TB USB]`

My problem is that this has not been reflected in Windows Explorer / My Computer. The old labels are displayed:

`Data (E:) [500 GB SATA]` `Data (F:) [2 TB SATA]` `Data Backup (R:) [500 GB USB]` `Data Backup (T:) [2 TB USB]`

If I look at the Properties for each drive from Windows Explorer this also shows the old labels.

I have tried re-labelling using Disk Management, Windows Explorer <kbd>F2</kbd>, the label.exe command line and Windows Explorer Properties window but nothing works.

How can I force Windows Explorer to show the correct labels?

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: I've only just managed to do so as it's our main media server in the house... Reboot has solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the simple answer! A reboot has solved the issue.